Why did my Hunter ceiling fan quit working after a storm?
I have a Hunter ceiling light/FAN in the bedroom. I do not have a remote; I just use wall switch. During a recent storm the fan stopped working but the light works. The fan is approximately 25 yrs old. Does this fan have a receiver even though no remote? Is this the likely problem that a new receiver would fix?

More likely the power wire for the fan has become loose/disconnected.  Is it a single wall switch or double, one for the fan, one for the light?  Turn off the breaker for the fan and check the switch first.  If it uses push in connection, move it to the screws.

Hunter fans, or any popular brand, would not normally have a receiver if it didn't come with a remote so a new receiver wouldn't do anything. However, they do have a capacitor that is normally housed in the lighting fixture area. Those usually go bad after years of working or from voltage/current  spikes and need to be replaced. Find yours and test it or just replace it because they are pretty cheap.

I also had one that fell victim to a lightning strike.  After that storm it would only go one way.
